# How to store large numbers of Python dictionaries in a datastore and filter/query it?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

I have a python dictionary with the following fields:

```
{
    "attribute_a": "3898801b-4595-4113-870b-ee5906457edf", # UUID
    "attribute_b": "50df4979-7448-468a-994c-96797b0f958b", # UUID
    "attribute_c": "0f6b2331-f86b-4e76-9efe-42ef8d843273", # UUID
    "attribute_d": "blah1", # string
    "attribute_e": "blah2", # string
    "attribute_f": "72.154.80.0", # IP Address
    "attribute_g": "blah3", # string
    "created_timestamp": datetime.datetime.now() # datetime
}
```

Now comes the hard part: I will have about 3 millions such records created daily and I need to store at least the last 90-days worth of these records in some type of datastore.

Once each record is stored, it will never need to be updated (but it can be deleted). And I will need the ability to occasionally query this datastore to find all records based matching any of the first 7 attributes and/or date comparison with the last attribute `created_timestamp`. Mostly I will only be filtering on `attribute_a` and will want to see the matching records sorted by `created_timestamp`.

Which datastore should I use?  I fear that if I tried to store this vast quantity of data in a MYSQL table with even one index on it, that much data will cause the insertions to become too slow. And if there are no indexes on it, then querying it becomes impossible. So I'm leaning towards a NoSQL solution like MongoDB.

However, I have no experience with NoSQL and am concerned if I can use it for this purpose. Will I be able to filter across multiple fields? Will it be able to handle the `created_timestamp` field as an actual date instead of as a string? Should I set one `attribute_a` as the primary key and all the other attributes as secondary global keys? If i do so, will inserts become exceedingly slow? Can it return the data to me date-sorted by `created_timestamp`?

Comment: Will your query result contain one or multiple objects after query? Cause mongodb can handle 16MB of data at once in its pipeline. And the amount of data you are talking about is too much.

Comment: There could be multiple such records in response to a query.